python 3.9 multiprocessing.RLock on windows 10
Here is my code:
from multiprocessing import Process, RLock
import os

LOCK = RLock()

def acquire_lock():
    r = LOCK.acquire()
    print(os.getpid(), "lock acquired:", r)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    acquire_lock()

    process1 = Process(target=acquire_lock)
    process1.start()

    process2 = Process(target=acquire_lock)
    process2.start()

    process1.join()
    process2.join()

With the above code, I'd expect one line printed to the stdout and the execution should not exit; but I get three lines, and the execution exited:
C:\workspace\nap\nap_test\validator>\apps\Python39\python.exe .\rlock.py
36660 lock acquired: True
20624 lock acquired: True
36792 lock acquired: True

C:\workspace\nap\nap_test\validator>

Same result swicthing from RLock to Lock.
Is the use of multiprocessing.RLock in the above code snippet correct?

I get the expected behavior.

Don't know if this is related to my python installation on windows. The code works as expected on ubuntu & python3.10 in WLS.
